# Way to display individual data from MySQL database on React.js?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, mysql-workbench, user-profile

**Is there a way that individual data from the MySQL database will be displayed on the react.js pages, like user profile?**

*This is my user profile but it display all the data on the database. How I can display single data? For example the information of the Student number 1. const getStudent is where the connection happen from the backend*

**Front end**

```
 import React from "react";
    import { useState } from "react";
    import Axios from "axios";
    import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"; 
    function Profile() {
      const [studentList, setStudentList] = useState([]);
    
      let navigate = useNavigate();
    

      const getStudent = () => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/students").then((response) => {
          setStudentList(response.data);
        });
      };
    
     
    
      return (
        <div className="students">
          <button onClick={getStudent}>Show Students</button>
          <h3>
          </h3>
          {studentList.map((val, key) => {
            return (
              
              <div className="student">
                <div>
                  <h3>Email: {val.email}</h3>
                  <h3>Password: {val.password}</h3>
                  <h3>Student Number: {val.student_num}</h3>
                  <h3>First Name: {val.first_name}</h3>
                  <h3>Middle Name: {val.middle_name}</h3>
                  <h3>Last Name: {val.last_name}</h3>
                  <h3>Year Level: {val.year_lvl}</h3>
                  <h3>Section: {val.section}</h3>
                </div>
               
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default Profile;
```

key is the name of the column

**The connection of the mysql/ BackEnd**

```
app.get("/students", (req, res) => {
      db.query("SELECT * FROM student", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.send(result);
        }
      });
      
    });
```